# The current Dart SDK version is 2.18.0

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Because agora_uikit_example requires SDK version >=2.18.1 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because agora_uikit_example requires SDK version >=2.18.1 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1

my yaml.xml file is below:

```
name: agora_uikit
description: Flutter plugin to simply integrate Agora Video Calling or Live
  Video Streaming to your app with just a few lines of code.
version: 1.3.2
homepage: https://www.agora.io/en/
repository: https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/VideoUIKit-Flutter

environment:
 sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
#  flutter: ">=2.2.0"

dependencies:
  agora_rtc_engine: ">= 6.1.0 <6.2.0"
  agora_rtm: ^1.5.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.13.5
  lints: ">=1.0.1 <2.1.0"
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  plugin:
    platforms:
      android:
        package: io.agora.agora_uikit
        pluginClass: AgoraUikitPlugin
      ios:
        pluginClass: AgoraUikitPlugin

analyzer:
  strong-mode: true
  errors:
    mixin_inherits_from_not_object: ignore
```

i want to run successfully. but i can not run. always throw above message. thanks

Comment: Ow!  Your minsdk is 2.7!  Does that mean the project is not yet migrated for null safety?  If so you have LOTS of work to do.  Google for "dart migration" for details and many guides.